# Is it possible HTTP Public Key Pinning on shared servers?

Tags: pinning

Is it possible HTTP Public Key Pinning (HPKP) on shared servers?

How to make this using php?

Comment: It might be possible, but the only reason to use HPKP is if you care about security; shared web hosting is the exact opposite of secure.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Why do you think you think you need it and that have you tried to do to enable it and where are you running into problems? On a side note: Please, please, please do NOT use HPKP unless you fully understand it - it should be considered a very advanced security feature.